# Strong induction multiple base cases

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Do you always need multiple base cases for strong induction? If you are trying to prove $\forall n. P(n)$, can the induction hypothesis be something like:

Assume $P(i)$ is true for all $i$ in $1\leq i\leq n$ where $n\geq 1$?

Comment: Am pretty sure you do not always need.  In fact probably usually does not need.  As n arbitrary in this case for example.